# libraries django to read, analize and create xlsx-csv files

Tags: python, django

I must create a web app with django that reads an xlsx file, a csv file and after their "data analysis" create a third xlsx file that contains the results of the data analysis.

My question is that: which libraries may I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use xlrd https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd library.